# How to create a multi vendor Drupal commerce website?

Tags: 7, commerce

What is the best way to create a multi vendor Drupal commerce website in which every vendor has the option to create:

1. Their own store.
2. Their own menu/vocabulary.
3. Every vendor have access to its own menu/vocabulary.

A hint would be enough.

Comment: Building sites or complex features from scratch is something we specifically don't do here. Please break your questions down into smaller requests, as you come across them during your own development. Have a read through the [help] to get a better idea of what to ask here. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

eCommerce in Drupal generally comes down to 2 modules:

- Ubercart
- Commerce.

[Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) is very powerful and flexible, and I'm sure you could use it to build your use case, but it might take a lot of work. It has a great distro called [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) to get you up and running quickly. And Pantheon will give you free hosting for you dev site and install the distro for you!

[Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) is older, and still powerful, not quite as flexible. But this module may meed your use case exactly: [Ubercart marketplace.](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace.)

Other module :

- [Commerce-Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace)

Comment: Commerce Marketplace  + Private Taxonomy Term maybe help to solve the use case

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "hint" you're asking for: use the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module (in Drupal 7), and combine it with a "multi-site" setup (1 site for each vendor).

So that all shops are running the same "software", but each Vendor has the access for "their" shop as you're asking for.

**Note**: if you have like "100" vendors (as in your comment below my answer here), maybe you'd then want to create (eg) 10 Drupal installations with each 10 sites (or 20 installations with each 5 sites). And/or you  could also consider the technique of "table prefixes" to have multiple sites share the same (single) database (with a prefix that corresponds to each vendor).

Comment: Wonderful, up to my experience maintaining multi-site is difficult if you have 100 or more different vendor/sites. As it will have 100 different databases

Comment: Well, the "100" was not really part of your original question (only "multi"). But maybe you'd then want to create  (eg)10 Drupal installations with each 10 sites (or 20 installations with each 5 sites). And/or you could could also consider the technique of "table prefixes" to have multiple sites share the same (single) database (with a prefix that corresponds to each vendor).

Comment: Much appropriated ! Let me see if this is what i need.